# Shell Scripting: Check Time with a case Statement

Tags: shell, date

I got a variable with the actual time.

```
time=$(date +"%H:%M")
```

Now I want to check (with a case Statement) to which day time it belongs to.

The Range are `06:00 to 12:00`, `13:00 to 18:00`, `19:00 to 22:00` and `23:00 to 05:00`.

How can I tell in which of these ranges is my actual time?

Comment: case  $time  in
             pattern
I don't know what I should use as a pattern to get the result

Comment: sure but I can't find a solution so I don't no what to do anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working on top of this wonderful [Stéphane Chazelas's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65312) for doing arithmetic on case-construct and my own logic to process date values using `GNU date`, a script like this below should solve your problem.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Date in (HH:MM) format: " inputdate

numDate=$(date -d"$inputdate" +"%H%M")

case $((
  (numDate >= 0600 && numDate <= 1200)   * 1 +
  (numDate >= 1300 && numDate <= 1800)  * 2 +
  (numDate >= 1900 && numDate <= 2200) * 3 +
  (numDate >= 2300 && numDate <= 0500) * 4)) in
  (1) echo "In time range between 06:00 to 12:00";;
  (2) echo "In time range between 13:00 to 18:00";;
  (3) echo "In time range between 19:00 to 22:00";;
  (4) echo "In time range between 23:00 to 05:00";;
  (0) echo "None of the above";;
esac
```

The logic is parse the input date to just actual numbers with `GNU date's` option `+"%H%M"` and working on the return values of the evaluation.